# Camel: is it possible to start a block in java DSL?

Tags: apache-camel

Through Googling and searching the Camel docs I have not found a way to start a block within a Camel multicast statement in Java DSL.

For example, what I imagine is something like this:

```
from("direct:dummy")
    .multicast()
        .begin().setHeader("A","toto").process(doSomething).end()
        .begin().setHeader("A","titi").process(doSomethingElse).end()
;
```

Where the hypothetical "begin()" would start a block. Is there such a construct ? Is there any other way to do something like this ?

The alternative I'm using at the moment is defining one "direct" per block, but in some cases (just setting a header in particular), this makes the code harder to read.

In my example, the alternative would look like:

```
from("direct:dummy")
    .multicast()
        .to("direct:dummy.toto")
        .to("direct:dummy.titi")
;

from("direct:dummy.toto")
    .setHeader("A","toto")
    .process(doSomething)
;

from("direct:dummy:titi")
    .setHeader("A","titi")
    .process(doSomethingElse)
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use .pipeline() instead of .begin() as your block

Comment: Great ! Thanks, I had missed that one :)